# Network error with axios and react native

Tags: react-native, axios

I have created an API endpoint using the Django python framework that I host externally. I can access my endpoint from a browser (`mydomain.com/endpoint/`) and verify that there is no error. The same is true when I run my test django server on locally on my development machine (`localhost:8000/endpoint/`). When I use my localhost as an endpoint, my json data comes through without issue. When I use my production domain, axios gets caught up with a network error, and there is not much context that it gives... from the debug console I get this:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:554)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:387)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:493
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:353)
    at MessageQueue.js:118
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (MessageQueue.js:316)
```

This is my axios call in my react native component:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('mydomain.com/get/').then(response => {  // localhost:8000/get works
            this.setState({foo:response.data});
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to have some sort of logger to see the request and response to make sure what the actual network error is

Comment: Is this happening on iOS, Android, or both?

Comment: @SeanWang Is there something you were thinking of? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @ajthyng iOS, haven't tried android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios (in React-native) not calling server in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)

Comment: The solution to these error can vary and the error message is not very helpful. For those that might still run into the same problem, if you want to get helpful error messages that will help you debug, use `console.log(error.response)`. I spent a whole day before I saw this in [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It seems that unencrypted network requests are blocked by default in iOS, i.e. `https` will work, `http` will not.

[From the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html):

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL.
>   If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http)
>   you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception.

Comment: Also, if you're connecting to a remote host, make sure that your SSL intermediate certificates are correctly established. Use https://www.digicert.com/help/ to check them.

Comment: I have https but it's doesn't work yet do you know another way for this ?

Comment: @smilebomb please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180455/how-to-soul-payment-gateway-using-stripe-error-in-react-native

Comment: please check this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5366

Comment: It is also true for Android starting from Android 9: 
"On Android, as of API Level 28, clear text traffic is also blocked by default. This behaviour can be overridden by setting android:usesCleartextTraffic in the app manifest file."

Answer (score 75):

If you are trying to call localhost on android simulator created with AVD, replacing localhost with 10.0.2.2 solved the issue for me.

Comment: Works! For example "http:// localhost:8000/" becomes "http:// 10.0.2.2:8000/"

Comment: Yep, also works on my side. Thanks man

Comment: Awesome... and weird at the same time. What's this IP? It's the mapping equivalent of my pc on the AVD?

Comment: Life saver comment!

Answer (score 29):

**If you do not find your answer in other posts**

In my case, I use Rails for the backend and I tried to make requests to `http://localhost:3000` using Axios but every time I got `Network Error` as a response. Then I found out that I need to make a request to `http://10.0.2.2:3000` in the case of the android simulator. For the iOS simulator, it works fine with `http://localhost:3000`.

### Conclusion

use

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:3000
```

### update

might worth trying

```
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

Comment: http://localhost:3000 it's doesn't work for IOS and then I changed the http to https it's still doesn't work

Comment: @MEAbid make sure ip and port is correct. Also, check firewall settings.

Answer (score 26):

1. change from **localhost** to your **ip(192.168.43.49)**
2. add **http://**

   http://192.168.43.49:3000/user/

Comment: thats work for me. I am development on expo. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Try
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
Accept: "application/json"

Answer (score 3):

For me, the issue was because my Remote URL was incorrect.
If you have the URL is a .env file, please crosscheck the naming and also ensure 
that it's prefixed with REACT_APP_ as react might not be able to find it if named otherwise.

In the .env file Something like REACT_APP_BACKEND_API_URL=https://appurl/api
can be accessed as const { REACT_APP_BACKEND_API_URL } = process.env;

Answer (score 3):

If you are using android then open your command prompt and type ipconfig. Then get your ip address and replce it with localhost.

In my case, first I used http://localhost:8080/api/admin/1. Then I changed it to http://192.168.1.10:8080/api/admin/1. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned answers only works if you are using localhost but if your code is hosted on a server and Axios throwing Network Error then you can solve this  by adding one line.

```
const config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: `${BASE_URL}/login`,
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'.  <----- Add this line in your axios header
  },
  data : formData
};


  axios(config).then((res)=> console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

If both your React Native application and your service are on the same local network, you can access your service using your local network IP.

**1. Find Your Local IP Address:**

- On your computer where the service is running, open a terminal and run the following command:

> ifconfig

- Look for your network interface (usually eth0 or en0) and find the inet address. It will be something like 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x. This is your local IP address.

**2. Update Your React Native App:**

- In your React Native app, make sure you're using the local IP address of your computer instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 to make requests to your service.
- Replace http://localhost:8080 or similar with http://your-local-ip:8080 (replace your-local-ip with the actual IP address you found in step 1).
- For example, if your local IP is 192.168.1.100 and your service is running on port 8080, your URL would be http://192.168.1.100:8080.

**3. Test on Other Devices:**

- Make sure your React Native app is running on a device or emulator connected to the same local network.
- Access the service using the local IP address you found in step 1.
- For example, if your local IP is 192.168.1.100, you would access the service on other devices using http://192.168.1.100:8080.

This should allow devices on your local network to communicate with your service. Remember to ensure that your firewall or security settings allow incoming connections on the specified port (in this case, 8080).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

i looked deeper and my

> endpoint `url` was not correct.

By giving `axios` right exact url, my api worked like charm.

Hope it may help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change `localhost` to `your_ip_address` which you can find by typing `ipconfig` in Command Prompt

Trying adding to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ***apisauce*** dependancy & Adding header work for me with React Native Android.

**Attach header with request like below:**

```
import { create } from 'apisauce';

    const api = create({
    baseURL: {baseUrl},
    headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
    });

export async function empLogin(data) {
   try {
         const response = api.post('Login', data);
         return await response;
   } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
         return [];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3456/apt")
  .then(
    response => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      ....
    } 
)
.catch(function(error) {
   alert(error.message);
  console.warn(error.response._response);
});
```

I was getting the following error:

> Error "Network error" Failed to connect to the localhost

After that, I made some steps to resolve the error.

Network Error related to axios resolved by disabling the system firewall and access from the system IP Address like:

```
axios.get("http://192.168.12.10:3456/apt")
  .then(
    response => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      ....
    } 
)
.catch(function(error) {
    alert(error.message);
    console.warn(error.response._response);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding "Accept" in headers resolved the problem:

```
Accept: 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues while connecting to localhost from react-native app.
you can do following steps

1- goto cmd type ipconfig.
2- replace localhost with your ip version 4
3- try again.. it will succeed.

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Background : App stack**

We faced the same error 'axios network error 500'.  We use an nginx proxy to forward all requests to an internal python Tornado server running at custom port.  And we have a react native js which handles frontend uploads.

**Root cause Analysis**

Since we were getting a 'network' error and none of the other fixes helped us, we traced through the flow thgrough the network:  browser -> server -> nginx -> tornado -> react -> html. We found the issue was at 'nginx'.

We had set up a standard default reverse proxy setup and never defined any file upload size limits explicitly in nginx.  It turns out by default only 1 MB upload is allowed.

So within the conf.d, we explicitly set client_max_body_size in both server and the inner location and restarted nginx.

Now, nginx started allowing files upto 200MB and this reached tornado and the js.  It worked :)

**Solution**

```
server
{
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        ssl_certificate xxx;
        ssl_certificate_key xxx;
        server_name abc.com www.abc.com;

        location /
        {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:866/;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
 }
```