# 'Axios' show Error: Network Error on server returning with 200 http status

Tags: node.js, react-native, api, axios, multipartform-data

I am using `axios: "^0.19.0"` to create get and post requests in `react-native 0.60.4`, but even after backend returning HTTP status code 200 `axois` showing `Error: Network Error`. Working perfectly on iOS but not on Android.

My request:

```
export default function uploadImageWithData(formData, url = "createGroup") {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: BASEURL + "api/webservice/" + url,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${global.authToken}`
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: what is your BASEURL

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani BASEURL="http://192.168.0.104:3057/"

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370747/network-error-with-axios-and-react-native

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I have already checked it out and tried with my test env BASEURL="https://musictest.giggleapps.net/" but getting the same error.

Comment: Have you used "http://" instead of "https://" ?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Tried with both "http://" and "https://".

Comment: check your internet permission in android manifest too. I hope that's your problem:)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with formData, in formData empty array appending in formData causing the issue(For Android).