# React native network error when post data with axios

Tags: react-native, axios

When I try to post data with axios it gives a network error without any information. I'm using python fast api as the backend and it works fine. I also tried to change my network address from ip address to localhost address but it also didn't work.

error log

```
 LOG  [AxiosError: Network Error]
 LOG  [AxiosError: Network Error]
 LOG  [AxiosError: Network Error]
 LOG  [AxiosError: Network Error]
```

react native code

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const params = {
      id,
      month,
      day,
      time,
    };

    axios
      .post("https://0.0.0.0:8080/prediction", params)
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data.data;
        const parameters = JSON.stringify(params);
        const msg = `Parameters: ${parameters}\nPrediction: ${data.prediction}`;
        alert(msg);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.view1}>
      <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Time predictor</Text>

      <View style={styles.inputview}>
        <TextInput label="ID" value={id} onChangeText={(text) => setId(text)} />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputview}>
        <TextInput
          label="Month"
          value={month}
          onChangeText={(text) => setMonth(text)}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputview}>
        <TextInput
          label="Day"
          value={day}
          onChangeText={(text) => setDay(text)}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputview}>
        <TextInput
          label="Time"
          value={time}
          onChangeText={(text) => setTime(text)}
        />
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => handleSubmit()}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

python code

```
@app.post("/prediction")
async def get_predict(data: Item):
    feature_list = []

    feature_list.append(int(data.id))
    feature_list.append(int(data.month))
    feature_list.append(int(data.day))
    feature_list.append(int(data.time))

    pred_value = prediction(feature_list)

    return {
        "data": {
            'prediction': pred_value
        }
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try passing headers -  axios.post('url', {"body":data}, {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
)

Comment: Are you trying in real device or emulator/Simulator - make sure both your system and testing device/simulator/emulator is connected to the same wifi or network.

Comment: @Kailash I tried it but still getting the same error. There is no other information in the console.

Comment: `axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/login',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Finn',
    lastName: 'Williams'
  }
});` try this way once.

Comment: @Kailash I'm using both web browser and the expo app to testing the app and all are in the same wifi network. And I'm using linux as my development environment.

Comment: Does your api working in postman ? I'm doubting your api url as well.

Comment: @Kailash Yes api is working fine. Also I tried it with the react.js it also working there correctly, but the problem occurs only in the react native. I wrote the above code like that axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/prediction",
      data: { id: id, month: month, day: day, time: time },
    })  but no luck

Comment: You have added wrong url , use -  `url: "https://0.0.0.0:8080/prediction"` , If doesn't work then try with `http`  once.

Comment: At last do follow  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370747/network-error-with-axios-and-react-native

hope it will work for you.