# AxiosError: Network Error on Expo React Native using Axios or Fetch only happens on Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, axios, expo

I am developing an application in expo react native, I am facing an error since a week ago, I make api calls to any public or test api and the request passes normal, but when I try to make a call to our working api it shows the error of [AxiosError: Network Error], this only happens in Android but in IOS it works correctly, the data being sent is FormData.
I'm using the latest version of Axios and React Native
Doing debug, it seems that the call doesn't even go out or reach the api, we tried to open more ports from the API but it doesn't seem to work at all.

I tried to downgrade the axios version and trying to make the call on fetch but happens the same, on fetch appears the same "Network Error"
I tried to run the app on a physical phone and even tried to run it after i built the APK

I FOUND A SOLUTION:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4406#issuecomment-1058701729

I changed the code to this form and the request came out without any problem.

```
const formData = new FormData();
...
const response = await networking.post('/URL', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  transformRequest: (data) => {
    return data; // thats enough
  },
});
```

Comment: You should check this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted?rq=2

Comment: There's some typo errors(misspelling, missing word),, but it isn't that big of an issue I think

Answer (score 0):

I commented on this some time ago and hope it works for you.
Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59588664/12369564

[image]

Comment: Thanks Esteban but I forgot to say that the api is already in production, I am not working on localhost anymore

Answer (score 0):

During a few days searching, I realized that the service where I was sending the Request, was rejecting the request in android because there was a problem completing the SSL certificate, what I did was to send an "intermediate certificate" between the request on my side in the nodeJS backend and so I got it to work.