# React Native Axios POST request provides "Network Error"

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, httprequest

I am trying to get data from a API with axios and basicly whatever I do, I always get the error "Network Error". I have tried many different ways but couldn't make it work. I have an JWT authentication, but the POST request is only working in Google Chrome.

AuthContext.js

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BASE_URL } from "../config";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);

  const login = async (username, senha) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, {
        username: username,
        password: senha,
      });

      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }`your text`

      const authorizationHeader = response.headers.authorization;
      console.log('JWT:', authorizationHeader);

      const body = response.data;
      console.log('Response Body:', body);

      return body;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setUserToken(null);
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("userToken");
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const isLoggedIn = async () => {
    try {
      let userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");
      setUserToken(userToken);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`isLoggedIn error ${e}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    isLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoading, userToken, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

configs.js

```
`export const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080";`
```

I tried to fetch data with a baseURL, and was expecting a successfull login query

Comment: Check if the backend is blocking you because of `CORS`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network error with axios and react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370747/network-error-with-axios-and-react-native)