# LOG [TypeError: Network request failed] react native

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, token

I've been trying to fetch data from Django ,
so I can create a react native app, I wrote the same method using useEffect,and it worked with me when I created web app,
and now when I use it with react native, I still got [TypeError :Network request failed ], is it because  the Token?

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movie/',{
        method:'GET',
        headers:{
            'Authorization':`Token f4136c8a15e73530edf6660d0062813362f6a02b`,
        }
    }).then(resp=>resp.json())
    .then(resp=>console.log(resp))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
},[])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network error with axios and react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370747/network-error-with-axios-and-react-native)