# Axios request returns error in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I use this same function in my Web App built in React. However, when I use it in React-Native (I am a newbie to React-Native) I am getting a Network error if I `console.log(err)` in my catch and get the following error:

```
Network Error
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:14 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:87:13 in XMLHttpRequest.handleError
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I'm not really sure why this is occuring in the node_module itself.

**Axios Request**

```
 // Login - Get User Token
    export const loginUser = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
        axios
            .post('/api/user/login', userData)
            .then((res) => {
                ....
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err); <--- Hit's catch
                dispatch({
                    type: 'GET_ERRORS',
                    payload: err.response.data
                });
            });
    };
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost)?

Comment: OMG...I looked at this and was thinking na I should be good on that...This fixed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios (in React-native) not calling server in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost)

Comment: If you console "err.response", you can get detailed info about error