# react-native, can't access verbose local IP address from web candidate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flask, axios, get

I'm developing on Windows 10.

Currently working with a Python (Flask) API that's hosted on port `5000` that returns static JSON.

This is what I'm calling from my React Native TS:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.*.*:5000/feed`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.data,
        log: "It loaded yaaaaay"
      });
    });
  }
```

*(obviously the astericks are stand-ins for my actual IP address)*

`this.state.log` returns the expected information when I specify any other test IP address outside my home network. I have also tested my API using both Insomnia and my web browser, and I get the expected JSON response.

Right now, the `then` function never appears to complete given the IP address in the example above.

My Flask script is currently running inside of a Docker image, while my React Native script is running natively.

My Firewall has been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If its localhost you'll want to use 10.0.2.2 instead of 192.168...

Look here for more information [Axios (in React-native) not calling server in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost)