# Post not working on axios with React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

Supposely I have the same post request on Postman and in a React Native code the Postman request executes successfully but the axios post request fails. On the console I just get "axios network error".

```
axios
.post("http://localhost:3000/passageiros", 

    {
        nome: "Diego",
        celular: "898",
        senha: "23232323",
      
      }
)
.then((response) => {
  setPost(response.data);
});
```

I've tried several approaches to check the error but just the generic erro "axios network error" shows.

Comment: Are you using the Android emulator? Localhost won't work if so, you need your local IP instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios (in React-native) not calling server in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost)

Comment: I am running my app with expo tools on an android device. God it does make sense localhost means nothing to the app. I will try to use the IP running the node backend.