# Response Error: [AxiosError: Network Error]

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am getting this Response Error: [AxiosError: Network Error] on my React Native project.
I am trying to connect a React Native App with a MySQL Database.

I have researched a lot, and most developers say it is mostly caused by the base url http://localhost:5000; it should follow protocol http, but I have added it but am still getting the error.

I have already installed dependencies, include

`npm install axios`

`npm install cors`

**auth.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

// Replace this with your backend server URL
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';




// Function for user sign-up
const signUp = async (email, password, fullName) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/signup`, { email, password, fullName });
    console.log(response.data); // Handle the response from the server
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // Handle any errors that occur during the request
  }
};

// Function for user login
const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, { email, password });
    const token = response.data.token;
    console.log(token); // Use the token for subsequent authenticated requests
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // Handle any errors that occur during the request
  }
};

export { signUp, login };
```

**backend/index.js**

```
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// Replace these values with your MySQL database credentials
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'beba_connect',
});

// MySQL connection test
db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL database:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database');
});



// Sign-up route
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, email, password } = req.body;

  // Hash the password before storing it in the database
  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error hashing password:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
      return;
    }

    // Insert user data into the database
    const newUser = {fullName, email, password: hashedPassword };
    db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newUser, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error inserting user:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        return;
      }

      res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
    });
  });
});

// Login route
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Retrieve user data from the database based on the email
  db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error retrieving user:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
      return;
    }

    if (results.length === 0) {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'User not found' });
      return;
    }

    const user = results[0];

    // Compare the password with the hashed password in the database
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error comparing passwords:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        return;
      }

      if (!isMatch) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid password' });
        return;
      }

    const secretKey = 'e604733c3ae40d201fe774c86ab1ec09e941eb48bba8fe31e9cccc8085ce058c';
     const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
      res.json({ token });
    });
  });
});

// Start the server
const port = 5000; // Change this to your preferred port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

where I am going wrong? kindly help

Comment: I have so many questions it's hard to know where to start... Why are you setting the default content-type headers to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when you've only registered the `bodyParser.json()` middleware? Why are you using `crossDomain`, it's not even an option? Why do you have your own custom, incomplete CORS middleware when you've already got `app.use(cors())`? And finally, why are you trying to connect to `localhost` when there are hundreds of posts saying not to for [tag:react-native]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios (in React-native) not calling server in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost)

Comment: @Phil I forgot to remove it, it's not supposed to be there.

Comment: _"I forgot to remove it"_... of the 3 things I pointed out, which one is **it**?

Answer (score 0):

you need to config request header type = `application/json` format